# Is there any marquee effect behaviour in Primefaces..?

Tags: java, jsf-2, primefaces, jboss

Is there any marquee effect behaviour in Primefaces..? I want to display auto scrollable news feed in my JSF page with pure Primefaces tags. I have used marquee tag but it is depreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can scroll text/marquee primefaces using imageSwitch

```
<p:imageSwitch effect="scrollLeft">
    <ui:repeat var="data" value="#{bBean.listTempData}">
        <p:outputPanel>#{data.name}</p:outputPanel>
    </ui:repeat>
</p:imageSwitch>
```

Another option is to use `<f:verbatim>` tag

```
<f:verbatim><marquee>hello world!</marquee></f:verbatim>
```

Please see these blogs for further details. [Blog 1](http://angelcharlie.blogspot.com/2007/02/marquee-in-html-is-defined-using.html) , 
[Blog 2](http://nerdynotes.wordpress.com/)